# View controller being dismissed on tap

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a login view controller with user name and password text fields, login button, register button and UIImageView to display an image. In portrait mode, when I tap on username and password fields, it displays keyboard and I can enter text. But when my app is in landscape mode, I have this issue. When I tap on username field to enter text, the View controller is being dismissed. I coded in such a way that when I click on background, view controller gets dismissed but now, even when I click on view controller it is getting dismissed. But this works fine in portrait mode.  Here is my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the gesture directly to your view. All the other stuff in the view (your buttons, textfields, etc.) are also part of your view. You need to add the gesture to a sibling of those subviews.

Not :

```
-- View                <--- gesture added to this view
---- Textfield
---- Button
```

But:

```
-- View
---- BackgroundView   <--- gesture added to this view
---- Textfield
---- Button
```

Or:

```
-- View
---- BackgroundView   <--- gesture added to this view
---- Containerview
------ Textfield
------ Button
```

1. Create a subview and add it as a backgroundview in the controller
2. Add the gesture to this backgroundview

Comment: I am sorry but what ever you said went over my head. Can you please explain it in detail ? If it is working fine in portrait mode, then why am I facing it in landscape mode ? Can you please explain the reason for this. Thanks.

Comment: Well.. now you added the subview to you controller's view right? The view which also contains your textfield right? Try adding it to a different view which does not *contain* those elements but just lies underneath those elements. I can't tell for sure why this problem is occurring in landscape only. It this all of your code? Did you override layoutsubviews somewhere else? Btw, why are you removing self.view and not the whole controller in -backgroundTapped? Why not just present and dismiss a modal view controller: http://goo.gl/4JTLG